# Synonimize [backticks] and [backquote]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

We have both [backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backticks) and [backquote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backquote), and [backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backticks) even says:

> For questions relating to the backtick character (`), also known as the backquote, which has various special meanings in computing.

I'm familiar with the backtick for special kinds of delimiting, but there also seems to be a distinct use in Lisp where the preferred name is backquote singular, so there *might* be an argument for [lisp-backquote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lisp-backquote), but I would like to propose that we merge both into [backtick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backtick) in the singular, and add [backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backticks) and [backquote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backquote) as synonyms.

Answer (score 4):

No, these are the same character but two different operators. We can't mix them.

Answer (score 3):

I think that this is a bad idea. In [Common Lisp `](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_df.htm) is a reader macro with very specific usage; the CL Hyperspec calls this a *backquote*, and the community calls it both *backquote* and *quasiquote* (I note that we also have a [quasiquotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quasiquotes) tag). Both [Scheme](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.17) and [Racket](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quasiquote.html?q=quasiquote#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._quasiquote%29%29) have `quasiquote` syntax, where ` is effectively an abbreviation for `quasiquote`; this is also called both *backquote* and *quasiquote* in the standards and community. None of these communities calls this a *backtick* in connection with this functionality.

I think that we should leave these tags alone and let users decide which is more appropriate for their own purposes.

Comment: Thatnks for explaining the Lisp usage. Perhaps instead someone needs to add text describing this to the [tag:backquote] and [tag:quasiquote] - and perhaps these are the two that need synonimised?

Comment: @KenY-N -- the problem I see with making _backquote_ and _quasiquote_ synonyms is that sometimes one might refer to the backquote character itself (independent of any Lispy meaning) instead of the backquote/quasiquotation operation.

Comment: Is there any reason to have a tag for this symbol?

Comment: @Braiam -- that's a good question. It looks like about half of the questions tagged [tag:backquote] right now are not about Lisp-style quasiquotation; they are about Javascript, Bash, C++, TeX, etc. If _backquote_ and _quasiquotes_ were made synonyms, the _backquote_ tags on questions not relating to quasiquotation should perhaps be edited to _backtick_. [tag:quasiquotes] also has questions from R, Haskell, F#, and Scala. I don't see a big gain by merging any of these tags.